# totalVowels variable is not updating

Tags: javascript, regex

My little function doesn't seem to update the `totalVowels` variable.
My train of thought at the moment is: the argument is converted into an array, the array is iterated through, and if the index matches against my `vowel` regex, my `totalVowels` var will add 1 per each match.

I feel like the solution is right under my nose, but I've been changing lots of little things around to get this to work and I'm currently out of ideas.

```js
    function VowelCount(str) {
     let strArr = str.split('');
     let totalVowels  = 0;
     let vowel = /a|e|i|o|u/gi
     for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        if (strArr[i] === vowel) { totalVowels++ }
     }
     return totalVowels;
    }
    
    console.log(VowelCount('vowel'));
```

Comment: There's a space between `totalVowels` and `++` (line 6)

Comment: `strArr[i] === vowel` - regexes don't work this way (in JS at least).

Comment: sorry you updated your question with one of the answers, does that mean that you ahve a solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I just moved over the ++ sign per Sv443. I moved it around prior to uploading it here while I was troubleshooting and forgot about it. But the answer below from slider solved the problem.

Comment: @Sv443 The space shouldn't make a difference

Comment: so if that answered your question please mark it as answered so credit goes, where credit is due...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `strArr[i] === vowel` for your `if` condition check because you're using a regex:

```js
function VowelCount(str) {
  let strArr = str.split('');
  let totalVowels = 0;
  let vowel = /a|e|i|o|u/gi
  for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    if (strArr[i].match(vowel)) {
      totalVowels++
    }
  }
  return totalVowels;
}

console.log(VowelCount('hello there'));
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot about the match method ... whoops. Thank you!